# Error when upgrage IBM MobileFirst platform server from v7.1 to v8.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I got this error when upgrading I have tried to alter the APPCNTR_VERSION to lower version but does not help.
Any clue? Please help.

BUILD FAILED
D:\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\WorklightServer\post-install.xml:332: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\WorklightServer\post-install.xml:2096: Column APPCNTR_VERSION of table APPCNTR_VERSION does not contain a value recognized by this version : '8.0.0'.
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.getDatabaseVersionApplicationCenter(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:1053)
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.getDatabaseVersion(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:832)
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.checkDatabasesConnectivity(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:762)
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.execute(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:282)
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseIMWrapper.execute(ConfigureDatabaseIMWrapper.java:159)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppCenter can be upgraded by running manually the upgrade-appcenter-71-80-xxx.sql plus installing the new appcenter wars.

Comment: I have managed to upgrade MFP v8 but due to the drastic change, my analytics would not work now. I know it might be out of topic but do you know where to read about migration of analytics from v7.1 to v8.0. I have tried this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.analytics.doc/analytics/t_installing_on_liberty.html but it stuck after login (keep loading).